# Running angular from npm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I was previously using angular from a CDN, as follows.

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Loading the app index from node as follows.

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
```

However, in hope of trying to bundle everything using something like browserify... I have just npm installed angular, and included the angular from node_modules instead of the CDN as follows.

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

But, now it seems that my angular is not being recognised, as I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <               angular.js:1
```

How can I get my angular app to load, now that I am using the npm verison?

Comment: Use angular cli, its super easy to setup and get going, will solve lots of issues with getting angular started. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: @Paddy If I am not mistaken... the CLI is for Angular 2. I am still using Angular 1.4.

Comment: @greateful, sorry skimmed the 1.4.0 version. yes it is 2.0 >

Comment: this error has nothing to do with you include angular from node_modules.. error is somewhere else

Comment: @entre No. Everything is working exactly as it is, even now, if I switch back to the CDN angular version. The problem ONLY occurs when I comment out the CDN version, and use the angular.js from npm modules.

Comment: is your angular js path is relative to index.html, can you see if its present in the src tab of chrome dev tools

Comment: try to server it using express.static

Comment: @entre I just tried to check the angular.js from chrome sources... and you are right.. it appears to be displaying my index file instead... I am really confused.

Comment: @entre Oh wow.. I just tried adding the following in my app.js, `app.use("/node_modules", express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));`.. and it works. For some reason, my gut feeling is telling me that I shouldn't be serving/adding node_modules like that

Comment: @entre Perhaps I should just change it to `app.use("/node_modules/angular", express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular'));` and limit it to angular alone.

Comment: Hi, can you share your folder structure as well??

Answer (score 0):

use `express.static` to serve static contents, copy all the static content as part of build process to `public` dir or else use webpack

Comment: Okay, so just to confirm... you are basically saying that I should not be adding node_modules directly using `express.static` in my app.js (because adding it has enabled my app to run again), but rather I should be copying the content over to my client directory in the build process. Is that correct? And what would you say about using `browserify` with this?

Comment: I guess... if I use browserify, then I can simply include the resulting file within my client folder.

Comment: yes exactly.. use browserfiy/webpack which will do this automatically for you

Answer (score 0):

I assume your directory structure like

```
app
|-node_modules
|-src
   |-client
      |-index.html
   |-app.js
```

Pass the name of the directory that contains the static assets to the express.static middleware function to start serving the files directly through app.js.

```
/* app.js */
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../')));
```

Now add script tag like

```
<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: I understand the concept... but not your code completely. You have added via `express.static` the path `../`, but nowhere within the path do I see the mention of `node_modules`... or anywhere within `app.js` for that matter. How is anything from `node_modules` going to be recognised in the client side, if it is not permitted to do so in the app?

Comment: I just set the path of shareable assets. here current directory `__dirname` is  `<root-path>/app/src/`. so I set the path to app `path.join(__dirname,'../')`. now express middleware is able to access the all shareable assets under app, i.e under `node_module/angular/angular.js` through index.html. you add app.js code on top of your response sending code(mentioned in your question). hope this is useful.